# How to use Custom Socket Factory in apache FTPS Client

Tags: java, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I am using FTPClient to communicate with FTP server. Its working perfectly.

Apache providing API to FTPSClient to communicate with FTP server using SSL/TLS. But it is using their own socket factory. So, I could not access the socket session.

I want to create custom socket factory, and handle the socket session manually.

Please help me.

Comment: Handle the socket session how? There's not much you can do with it except invalidate it.

Comment: Instead of using API , need to handle by myself.

Comment: what do you want to do with the session?

Answer (score 1):

Although `FTPSClient` is a `SocketClient`, I find that it is not best to call  [`setSocketFactory(SocketFactory)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#setSocketFactory) on it as methods like `execProt(String)` and even the FTPS connection logic will make internal calls to `setSocketFactory(SocketFactory)`and undo your work.

I suggest setting the SSL context as an argument to the constructor, and/or using methods such as `setEnabledProtocols(String[])` and [`setTrustManager(TrustManager)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html#setTrustManager(javax.net.ssl.TrustManager)) to set the conditions for the countless SocketFactory objects that the Apache Commons code will create over the lifetime of your FTPSClient.

FYI: `TrustManager` objects and `SSLContext` objects can be configured to use your own trustStore and/or the JVM's default trustStore.